# How to get the all the messages from a telegram group?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have a telegram group of over 2000 users. And its almost active all the time.

Now I'm planning to create a live web app which will get all the messages from the group and show it on the web page, which will keep on updating as new messages arrive in the following format.

A: blah blah blah

B: blah blah to you too

C: Thanks blah blah etc.

Is there any bot or any other way in which I can get these messages?

Comment: Here is not place let you find library. Please search and ask friends first.

Comment: We cannot povide you a library, but help you with coding problems after you have chosen an API and tried to code it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a bot in the caht, use Telegram API with some code, deployed on server. Than you can set a [Webhook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook) to get a request on your server with an incoming new message and store the text of the message in database. Than you can set up a site with live-update after a new one message appears in your database.